# how to list files from a specific directories

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I have a list of directories in a text file can any one tell me how to list files only inside the directories which is in text file

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` and [`bash` Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) for that:

```bsh
find $(</path/to/path_file) -type f
```

This simply lists every `f`ile contained in every directory mentioned in `/path/to/path_file`. Of course you can tweak `find`'s output further, e.g. by adding the `-ls` option.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── path_file
├── test1
│   ├── 1
│   └── 2
└── test2
    ├── 3
    └── 4
$ cat path_file
/path/to/test1
/path/to/test2
$ find $(</path/to/path_file) -type f
/path/to/test1/2
/path/to/test1/1
/path/to/test2/4
/path/to/test2/3
```

I'm using absolute paths here, so it's irrelevant in which directory `find` is called. If the `path_file` contains *relative* paths you need to call it in the correct directory – imagine every `/path/to` replaced by `.` in the above example.

If your paths contain spaces you can set the [Internal Field Separator](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit) to newline with `IFS=$'\n'` before calling `find`, this way only newline will be be seen as a boundary between the paths.

---

If you want to go over every line I strongly recommend [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), to stay with `find`:

```bsh
parallel find {} -type f :::: /path/to/path_file
```

`parallel` handles whitespaces in the arguments correctly by design.

Comment: Thats how you teach them to swim.....just throw 'em in the water! lol

Comment: @stumblebee What's wrong and so complicated about command substitution? In fact, your answer uses it as well, just with the slower alternative `cat`. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems here: one is very simple - listing files in directories, and the other that can be a bit more troublesome - [reading file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and passing lines from that file as arguments.

Classic way to do so is via `while IFS= read -r` loop and we can add other stuff to it

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ] ; 
do 
    [ "x$line" = "x" ] && continue
    [ -d "./$line" ] && ls "./$line"
done < ./dirs.txt
```

There's couple things happening:

- `IFS=  read -r line` part will read a line without performing [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting); that means that if you have `<space><space>directory_name` it will be read exactly like that, instead of `directory_name` only.
- `./` next to checks for whether the said directory exists in the first place  and `ls` - that's to protect from filenames that may begin with `-`.  Filenames such as `-directory`  can be misinterpreted by commands as `-d` flag with corresponding value `irectory` for that flag; of course that will lead to an error if such flag doesn't exist for the command.
- `[ "x$line" = "x" ] && continue` will check for empty variable/blank line. If variable is empty, `ls` will output contents for `./`, which is wrong behavior.

---

Recursive case of the same thing could be either via `find` as dessert shows, or via `globstar`:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ] ; do 
    [ "x$line" = "x" ] && continue
    [ -d "$line" ] &&
    for i in "$line"/** ; do 
        ls "$i"
    done
done < "/path/to/dirs.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **simple example** to do that from the command line:

```
ls `cat ./dirs.txt`
```

Replace "dirs.txt" with the name of the file that contains the list of your directories. The `dirs.txt` file has to be in the current working directory unless you specify the path to `dirs.txt` To list the files one screen at a time:

```
ls `cat ./dirs.txt` | more
```

This will be more complicated As Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy has pointed out in the comments, this will not work correctly if your `dirs.txt` contains a directory has a space in it or tabs.

Comment: This will output error for lines in the text file that have spaces in them or tabs. I'd suggest you use `xargs` with `--arg-file` option to read in the file and then pass it to `ls`.  Please also read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @dessert  never used parallel myself, so can't comment on that :) What's with the `::::` though ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy This could get even more complicated if the directory has spaces in it.

Comment: @dessert  I never used parallel either. That is good info.

Comment: @dessert Yep, that. And I would also add `--no-run-if-empty`  to the flags of `xargs` just for the sake of completeness

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly know the script, but combining one of these inside a `for` loop in the script will do what you want to do.

To list **`files only inside a directory`** , you can do one of these

#### Using ls

```
$ ls -p | grep -v / 

OR

$ ls -al | grep '^-'
```

#### Using find

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```